# Solve integral $\int_\sqrt{x}^0 \sqrt{1+\sec^2 p}\ \mathrm dp $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

How would I go about solving the following integral:

$$T(x) = \int_\sqrt{x}^0  \sqrt{1+\sec^2 p}\ \mathrm dp $$

I went ahead and started by flipping the bounds, but am confused on next steps, this doesn't look like an identity to me but think that's probably the path to solving this integral.

Thank you for the help

Comment: [Please type out your questions in LaTeX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Some things: $T$ doesn't depend on $p$ but on $x$. Also, there is a closed form of $$\int \sqrt{1+\sec^2(p)}\,\mathrm dp$$ but it is not pretty

Comment: will need to use an integral table

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy You can use the following series of substitutions: $u=\sec^2(x)$, $s=\operatorname{arcsec}(u)$, $p=\tan(s/2)$ and then use partial fractions to get a very ugly closed form

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\sec^2x = 1 + \tan^2x$$

Therefore,
$$\int \sqrt{1 + \sec^2 x}\,\mathrm dx = \int \sec^2x\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2 + \tan^2x}}{1 + \tan^2x}\,\mathrm dx$$

Next, use the substitution $u = \tan x$.

As @maximilian-janisch mentions in the comment, the solution isn't pretty, but this is something to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Break up the integral as follows

\begin{align}
T(x)&=\int_{\sqrt x}^0 \sqrt{1+\sec^2 p}\  dp\\
&=\int_{\sqrt x}^0 \left(\frac{\cos p }{\sqrt{1+\cos^2 p}}+\frac{\sec^2 p }{\sqrt{1+\sec^2 p}}\right)dp\\
&= \int_{\sqrt x}^0  \frac{d(\sin p)}{\sqrt{2-\sin^2p}} + \int_{\sqrt x}^0  \frac{d(\tan p)}{\sqrt{2+\tan^2p}}\\
&=-\sin^{-1} \frac {\sin\sqrt x}{\sqrt2}
-\sinh^{-1}\frac {\tan\sqrt x}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

For the antiderivative, another solution could be
$$I=\int  \sqrt{1+\sec^2 (p)}\, dp=\int\sec ^2(p)\frac{\sqrt{\tan ^2(p)+2} }{\tan ^2(p)+1}\,dp$$ Now, let $q=\tan(p)$ to get
$$I=\int\frac{\sqrt{q^2+2}}{q^2+1}\,dq$$ Now, let $q=\sqrt{2} \tan (r)$ to make
$$I=2 \int \frac{ \sec ^3(r)}{2 \tan ^2(r)+1}\,dr$$ Now, let $r=\sin ^{-1}(s)$ to make
$$I=-2 \int \frac{ds}{(s^2-1)(s^2+1)}=\int\left(\frac{1}{s^2+1}+\frac{1}{2 (s+1)}-\frac{1}{2 (s-1)} \right)\,ds$$ that is to say
$$I=\tan ^{-1}(s)+\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{1+s}{1-s}\right)$$ and, back to $p$,
$$I=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan (p)}{\sqrt{\tan
   ^2(p)+2}}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{\sqrt{\tan ^2(p)+2}+\tan (p)}{\sqrt{\tan
   ^2(p)+2}-\tan (p)}\right)+C$$